# Route exact path="/" not working for react github

Tags: reactjs, github

I am confused. Still learning Reactjs though and I am having this issue. I uploaded my react app to github pages. The only thing not working is the homepage on load. I mean, when I visit the site link, it doesn't display the homepage except I click the homepage link on the navigation bar.

However, while on my local machine, the home page works fine onload. No issues at all. I am still a novice and will appreciate any help rendered. Here is my code.

```
import Single from './pages/single/single'
import Home from './pages/home/home'
import TopBar from "./components/topbar/TopBar";
import Write from './pages/write/write'
import Settings from './pages/settings/settings'
import Login from './pages/login/login'
import Register from './pages/register/register'
import {
BrowserRouter as Router,
Switch,
Route,
Link
} from "react-router-dom";

function App() {
const user = false;
return (
<Router>
  <TopBar/>
  <Switch>
    
    <Route exact path="/">
      <Home />
    </Route>

     
    <Route path="/register">
      { user? <Home/> : <Register />} 
    </Route>

    <Route path="/login">
      {user? <Home/> : <Login />}
    </Route>

    <Route path="/write">
      {user? <Write /> : <Register/>}
    </Route>

    <Route path="/settings">
      {user? <Settings />: <Register/>}
    </Route>

    <Route path="/post/:postId">
      <Single />
    </Route>


  </Switch>


   </Router>
 );
 }

 export default App;
```

Is there anything that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to update your import HashRouter instead of BrowserRouter

```
import { HashRouter } from "react-router-dom";
```

Alternatively, you can use a trick to teach GitHub Pages to handle 404 by redirecting to your index.html page with a special redirect parameter. You would need to add a 404.html file with the redirection code to the build folder before deploying your project, and you’ll need to add code handling the redirect parameter to index.html. You can find a detailed explanation of this technique in Here is the proper documentiotion to deploy SPA using at github pages [Link](https://github.com/rafgraph/spa-github-pages)

Comment: that worked. Thanks very much. Please, do you mind to explain to me why it worked. What was i doing wrong? Also, I noticed that with this method, my url now has # attached to them. Is that okay?

Comment: Yeah that is okay this is how hashrouter works. Github pages has some issues with browserRouter that is why I also use Hashrouter or alternate solution with link attached.

Comment: I had the same issue while using electron-boilerplate-react and this solved it for me